# Dynamodb equivalent to SQL case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Well im tryng to filter my Query result to get a fixed set of cases like

region = 'X' || 'Z' || 'C'

in SQL you can use CASE for this, how can i achieve this on dynamo? i didnt find on the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in SQL you would actually do this:

`select * from table where region in ['X', 'Z', 'C']`

It's not clear to me how you would use `CASE` for that.

DynamoDB also has a `IN` condition, [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html), so you could use a filter expression like:

```
FilterExpression: 'region IN (:region1, :region2, :region3)'
```

Comment: Important to note that DDB still reads (and consumes RCU) for the records it filters out.  Also that DDB only reads 1MB of records before it filters and returns...Query() has to be called in a loop to ensure you get back all matching records...